# opening powershell from inside vim

Tags: gvim, vim-windows, external-command, microsoft-windows

I want to run powershell from vim and I have achieved it using the following mapping:

```
map <leader>cd :cd %:p:h<cr>:silent !powershell<cr>
```

The problem is that I can't do anything inside vim until I close the powershell window which somehow defeats the purpose. How can I tell vim to let go of the opened powershell so I could make changes in the file open in vim.

Maybe I am searching with wrong keywords and that's why I couldn't find a solution.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `:terminal powershell`

Comment: This opens a new window *inside* vim (which is very hard to close, how do I close that window?). Is it possible to open the powershell window from inside vim and then vim let go of that window so I could modify the content inside vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
:silent !start powershell
```

Which should run a new powershell command in its own window, detached from the current vim instance.

See also:

- [Q&A on `:!start` on Windows](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/os_win32.txt.html#%3A%21start);
- [Documentation of the Windows `start` command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html), in particular you might want to look into `/D` to specify the startup directory for the command.

Comment: Thank you very much @Filipe. This is what I was looking for.